# Silverlight 5 trust application issue

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

In silverlight5 beta, it supports trust application which allows loading local files. I tried and it works fantastic in both OOB and in browser mode. One question is that, when put my cap on the server, it works fine in OOB mode but doesn't work in browser. I think debugging locally and deployment is different. Is there a way to request the trust in browser as I tried locally?

Thanks,
Howard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of steps needed:-

- The XAP needs to be signed using a code-signing certificate

Then on the client machine

- A tweak to the registry on the client machine that needs to run a trusted app inbrowser
- The code signing certificate then needs to be installed on the client machine.

Those last two in a real world deployment would be configured using a Group Policy.

See the Beta document topic [How to: Enable Trusted Applications to Run Inside the Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=VS.96%29.aspx).

Comment: It seems we cannot deploy the trust application in browser easily and automatically. I'm planing do some projects with this feature, maybe I will work on another way. :)

Comment: You can use Group Policy to both push [AllowInstallOfElevatedTrustApps](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/resources/documentation/grouppolicysettings.aspx#TrustedApplications) registry setting as well as [Deploy Digital Certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770315%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)